# how to write lists to specific columns of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a nested list and each nested list has multiple strings within:

```
[['http:/house.com/06','http:/google.com/09','http:6000.com'],['http:/house.com/04','http:/google.com/03','http:600.com', 'http://900.com],['http:/house.com/09','http:/google.com/076','http://rather.com']...]
```

my goal is to get the first element of each list in the first column, and get the rest in the second and third columns

wanted result in csv file:

```
col1                 col2                  co3            col4
http:/house.com/06   http:/google.com/09   http:6000.com
http:/house.com/04   http:/google.com/03   http:600.com    http://900.com
http:/house.com/09   http:/google.com/076  http://rather.com
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: The result you are showing is not a valid csv. Separator has to be same for columns and data. You have more whitespaces between columns and less whitespaces between data.

Comment: Many readers can handle multiple white space as one.   But having 3 values in one row, and 4 in another can give problems.  An explicit delimiter like `,` can make reading easier, even if the columns are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The separator should not change in the header row and data row. Since you have an empty strings in few rows you should go for the comma separator. Try it like so:

## With `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [['http:/house.com/06','http:/google.com/09','http:6000.com'],['http:/house.com/04','http:/google.com/03','http:600.com', 'http://900.com'],['http:/house.com/09','http:/google.com/076','http://rather.com']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=l1, columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4']).fillna('')
df.to_csv('file1.csv', index=None)
```

This is how the dataframe looks like:

[image]

## With `csv` package:

```
import csv

l1 = [['http:/house.com/06','http:/google.com/09','http:6000.com'],['http:/house.com/04','http:/google.com/03','http:600.com', 'http://900.com'],['http:/house.com/09','http:/google.com/076','http://rather.com']]
with open('file1.csv', 'w') as f:
    rows = [['col1','col2','col3','col4']] + l1
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: using external library is an overkill in that case

Answer (score 0):

CSV file columns are divided by COMMA (,), thus you can iterate over your data structure and print into file the following text:

```
col1,col2,co3,col4
http:/house.com/06,http:/google.com/09,http:6000.com,
http:/house.com/04,http:/google.com/03,http:600.com,http://900.com
http:/house.com/09,http:/google.com/076,http://rather.com,
```

you can achieve that with nested for loops

```
for x in lst:
   for y in x:
      print y + ","
```

Comment: I'm not following this, so the print y+ "," will lead to the csv result?

Comment: CSV can be comma separated or tab separated. And moreover this is not a complete answer. Try to improve it.

Comment: You can declare csv separator as tab also

Comment: Read the question once again carefully, you didn't understand what the OP is asking.